# Pulling JSON image data to the front-end using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I am trying to read a JSON file in javascript and to display the image key values on the front-end. To make it a bit more clear here is a snippet of my JSON file.

```
{ "products": 
    {"asin": "B000FJZQQY", "related": {"also_bought": 
       ["B000QY9N7G", "B0002FHIM6"], "also_viewed": ["B00DVLALEK", 
        "B0076S9MIK", "B000QY9N7G", "B000KUOII0", "B000FKK0U0", 
        "B001E471LW", "B008LO02RI", "B0018MMYXA", "B001FARMLE", 
        "B004R2SZL8", "B00ICSLQO6", "B000FKGTOG", "B000QYD4IA", 
        "B00BZBHHGS", "B00I5PMFZK", "B00774HBSQ", "B007R8T4M8", 
        "B00I4GJAAI", "B005R1SRKW", "B0013EDDVU", "B00FIV3Y8G", 
        "B0018TIUOK", "B008M0ZVHM", "B000HAR1ZK", "B003DW1FDI", 
        "B00LGXXLCO", "B008M2LTXU", "B009D3NZNE", "B0082C3MVM", 
        "B001FAX68W", "B00IELAS1I", "B001FARML4", "B001FAV4CM", 
        "B006QT1FFS", "B008M2UF9Y", "B0070QLQ2S", "B008ACKZWS", 
        "B00EISLWX4", "B00BXOI10S", "B000FFDDKY", "B00B05PTK0", 
        "B004N9A96E", "B008ACKRNU", "B00553GZM4", "B00B05P5UE", 
        "B003EHM4QE", "B00GBFWDIA", "B00LGXWIL4", "B001OR9WVG", 
        "B003JJ9TM4", "B001OR6CLO", "B00JG856IS", "B00DEUUBF2", 
        "B0031TQL7I", "B001ORBZFC", "B007D370NW", "B0088PCHJQ", 
        "B00LGXYTKM", "B0018MQAOY", "B000FKGTO6"], "bought_together": 
        ["B00DVLALEK", "B000FKK0U0", "B000QY9N7G", "B0076S9MIK"]}, 
        "title": "Plain Black Adjustable Hat", "price": 4.98, 
        "salesRank": {"Clothing": 11276}, "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-
         amazon.com/images/I/41iPLtrOkTL._SX342_.jpg", "brand": 
        "Gravity", "categories": [["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Men", 
        "Accessories", "Hats & Caps", "Baseball Caps"]]},
        {"asin": "B000O7CXCC", "title": "Tall Red Kap Industrial Short 
        - sleeved Work Shirt", "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-
        amazon.com/images/I/31Xd9t6H%2BlL._SX342_.jpg", "related": 
        {"also_bought": ["B0002FHIM6", "B000N8TKP0"], "also_viewed": 
        ["B007W58L3O", "B0058T4E8W", "B005HV4AA8", "B007VR3KXY", 
        "B007VPV2E0", "B00781QQ5M", "B0058T34EM", "B009A01884", 
        "B007WC38TO", "B000N8Q56C", "B00IOEG1C0", "B0055N5EBW", 
        "B00BLYRDIG", "B001GRV4EC", "B0058T46UI", "B0036GGNV0", 
        "B004QV9Z5A", "B003LO20AK", "B00BN37HHW", "B001JTAEPW", 
        "B004QV9Z4G", "B0035E8I8E", "B00IOEG9GI", "B00BLYRDJA", 
        "B00IOEG2PQ", "B007VPYC38", "B00DP0ODXW", "B007GC02RQ", 
        "B007W58XA0", "B007W58GHA", "B00CIZI71O", "B00520AI50", 
        "B004QVEWT4", "B007WC3IXA", "B0058T3Y5G", "B003C2KSIW", 
        "B00G293I8E", "B0011RLFKK", "B00IOEG6MA", "B00BLYRDI6", 
        "B007GBWMX4", "B00BLO09IM", "B00BLYRDH2", "B007GOH308", 
        "B003AQK9YS", "B007VR3DA4", "B005HV54Q2", "B00AYOYHYC", 
        "B0058T2XXU", "B0035E8MPS", "B00JD7FKTM", "B001IYAG1U", 
        "B005DDYQMW", "B00BB5WF7Y", "B004ZCE97E", "B0041T42AK", 
        "B00ENEK7JS", "B0058T3UK0", "B000C7VE3I"], "bought_together": 
        ["B007W58L3O", "B000N8Q56C", "B005HV4AA8"]}, "salesRank": 
        {"Clothing": 2878}, "categories": [["Sports & Outdoors", 
        "Clothing", "Men", "Shirts", "Button-Down Shirts"], ["Clothing, 
        Shoes & Jewelry", "Men", "Clothing", "Shirts", "Casual Button-
        Down Shirts"], ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Men", "Big & 
        Tall"]]},
        {"asin": "B000EZT5GG", "title": "Wrangler Men's Regular Fit 
        Jeans", "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-
        amazon.com/images/I/41Hs7LR7LpL._SX342_.jpg", "related": 
        {"also_bought": ["B000BUDM54"], "also_viewed": ["B0007G8W3O", 
        "B0007G8VTY", "B000F9WJ7S", "B000V766A0", "B001A4B6V2", 
        "B001A41F5O", "B006J64PKU", "B008O2EW6E", "B001A47L6G", 
        "B000FERNT2", "B000M65GY2", "B006K9XS9A", "B00KQQNLAO", 
        "B000JRABQM", "B000TW5HTS", "B006MATHAQ", "B008PFGLW8", 
        "B0029NYLH4", "B000FA2832", "B0006Z13N2", "B008PDF2F2", 
        "B000CEME62", "B003WE994E", "B006K9XU5C", "B008O2EWV4", 
        "B006K9XS9K", "B000CEQP80", "B008RAI9DA", "B008PDF2CK", 
        "B001A3ZI6C", "B006MC59GU", "B006BMLPE6", "B0018OMIMK", 
        "B006CDQPLM", "B000BLKYMW", "B006CDWKZW", "B000FEM3QA", 
        "B008OHTU1G", "B0018OR118", "B000N8X86W", "B006J64R9Y", 
        "B008PQTL7O", "B005GSXTV8", "B008PDF2QG", "B006K9XT12", 
        "B006GK8MBW", "B0008G26BM", "B000FW38YS", "B006B5VNPY", 
        "B006GJU2SY", "B00BCG1LI6", "B0007G8RKC", "B006K9XS8G", 
        "B008OHTUNO", "B006H2BKWM"], "bought_together": ["B0007G8W3O", 
        "B000V766A0", "B00KQQNLAO", "B0007G8VTY"]}, "salesRank": 
        {"Clothing": 5043}, "categories": [["Clothing, Shoes & 
        Jewelry", "Men", "Clothing", "Jeans"]]},
        {"asin": "B000KK2K9O", "title": "Vans Unisex VANS CLASSIC SLIP-
        ON SKATE SHOES", "imUrl": "http://ecx.images-
        amazon.com/images/I/41W2PniiwbL._SX395_.jpg", "related": 
        {"also_bought": ["B000A80JXA"], "also_viewed": ["B000A80JXA", 
        "B005IHDY62", "B005IHDBII", "B005IHLTLO", "B00DPZ4AIU", 
        "B00HU1US7C", "B00LI8U31Y", "B004HJUTZG", "B007JWW3PW", 
        "B00LI8N5S2", "B007QK45WG", "B00LMI786I", "B001CW0A5K", 
        "B005P7DFTQ", "B00JGE74T6", "B004IA1BWO", "B004EEFPKI", 
        "B00L028VNK", "B0015ZVJRW", "B007D47SJ2", "B00HVVRDVA", 
        "B007QK4OSG", "B00LDF00GA", "B000EPCDC4", "B00E0WLSGO", 
        "B00HPXW6UM", "B004LOI616", "B007JWPETO", "B00LMI8VT6", 
        "B00K4FMMH0", "B003YUU62U", "B001F7M7K8", "B00KFCLLCO", 
        "B0051PLZ5I", "B00E0WKF3G", "B00IGEN0MW", "B000LEB7LG", 
        "B00JXE8OZW", "B00LIB3TO4", "B004O27ZJE", "B005DHMASK", 
        "B00E0WL3D2", "B0043RSEXG", "B0012WJDL2", "B00FVJEZUG", 
        "B00LMI82VI", "B003FZK520", "B00LICMV9C", "B00KEJX482", 
        "B00KCNLJ0U", "B008YEZHYS", "B005IIVT7M", "B004HJR6KM", 
        "B00FVJF0O6"], "bought_together": ["B000A80JXA", "B001F7M7K8", 
        "B001CW0A5K", "B0000ESAUL"]}, "salesRank": {"Shoes": 3148}, 
        "categories": [["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Street, Surf & 
        Skate"], ["Clothing, Shoes & Jewelry", "Women"], ["Clothing, 
        Shoes & Jewelry", "Men"]]}
]}
```

Here is my javascript so far that only displays all the images for every products throughout the whole json file.

```
$(function() {

var products = []

$.getJSON('test.json', function(data) {
   $.each(data.products, function(i, f) {
    var Imgs = '<div class="Hats"><img src="' + f.imUrl + '"></div>'
    $(Imgs).appendTo($(".HatsImages"));
    var Imgs = '<div class="Tops"><img src="' + f.imUrl + '"></div>'
    $(Imgs).appendTo($(".TopsImages"));
    var Imgs = '<div class="Pants"><img src="' + f.imUrl + '"></div>'
    $(Imgs).appendTo($(".PantsImages"));
    var Imgs = '<div class="Shoes"><img src="' + f.imUrl + '"></div>'
    $(Imgs).appendTo($(".ShoesImages"));
    })

  })
})
```

and finally the html and css that is involved for this code to work.

```
    <article class="column large-2">

          <div class="HatsImages">

          </div>

          <div class="TopsImages">

          </div>

          <div class="PantsImages">

          </div>

          <div class="ShoesImages">

          </div>
        </article>


.Hats, .Tops, .Shoes, .Pants {
    display: none;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px; 
 }

.Hats:nth-child(1), .Pants:nth-child(1), .Tops:nth-child(1), 
.Shoes:nth-child(1) {
    display: block; 
}
```

So in javascript, I would like to read this json file and display the 'imUrl' value (also known as the image) in the either the  or the  or the  or the  (as you can see in the HTML) depending on what that it is an image of which you can find out by checking the 'title' or 'categories' key value. So for the use of this example lets so its an image of a Hat so it would be displayed in the 'HatsImages' div. I would then like to read the 'bought_together' key and for every asin value in that key find the original data for that asin. So let's say one of the asins was 'B000O7CXCC' then find the 'asin' that equals 'B000O7CXCC' and display the 'imUrl' key value also known as the image in the write div such as  or the  or the  or the  depending what its a picture of which you can find out by checking the 'title' or 'categories' then repeat this process for every 'asin' also known as the ID in the 'bought_together' key.

I hope this makes sense if any more information or explanation is needed please say.

Comment: Your explaining paragraph is really hard to digest... Can you reformat that and/or provide an actual example of what the result should be?

Comment: @Jeto Yeah sure

Comment: Your json file is not valid.
You can you https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com/ to reformat and valid your json.
It may be the source of your bug actually

Comment: @RadonirinaMaminiaina That must of been a mistake by me when copying and pasting, its not invaild anymore

Comment: For some reason when I copy and paste the json code from this thread it says its invaild but when i copy and paste the file from my local it doesn't but that isn't the reason why i cant get it to work

Comment: @Jake123 If I understand your question correctly, you are displaying hats in the hats div and now you want to display the bought_together items by searching for asin in the same list?

Comment: @AmanB yeah that's right but search for asin from the same json file

Answer (score 0):

You just have to loop through bought together list then searching inside the same productList in find items

```
$.each(data.products, function(i, f) {
    var Imgs = '<div class="Hats"><img src="' + f.imUrl + '"></div>'
    $(Imgs).appendTo($(".HatsImages"));

    f.bought_together.forEach(function(element) {
       var item = findItem(element, data.products);
      //Display the item ......
     });


});


function findItem(asin, productList){
 for(var i = 0; i < productList.length; i++)
 {
   if(productList[i].asin == asin)
   {
     return productList[i];
   }
 }
}
```